# Why do I have negative righteous resistance in Dungeons of Dredmor?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

My current player seems to have -7 righteous resistance. There does not appear to be any indication that I am suffering from an effect that causes this. Could it be a display bug?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that none of your skills are giving you that penalty. Demonology grants a righteous resistance penalty at higher levels, and there may be others as well.

Comment: Too bad i didn't realize that before. I'm seriously getting my arse handed to me by these cold-type monsters deeper in the dungeon. This is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Certain items or enemy skills may also apply a debuff to various resistances, including Righteous resistance. Try looking over all of the items you have currently equipped, then read through your active effects.